# How should I store two strings for a Mac App?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am making a web app which needs to store a user's email and password for a web service, which it then connects to. Rather than them have to enter this each time, I want it to save when the app closes.

How should I do this? Do I need to use core data or SQLite for just two strings, or is there another, better way to do  this?

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't it the user's browser that should be storing the password? In any event, use the Keychain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't store the password as plain text. *Even if it is supposed to be “unimportant” and “insecure”*. If possible, consider not storing it at all (store hash, for example, or get a cookie from the web service on first authorization). In that case, `NSUserDefaults` would be a standard and easy way for storing such data.

If you do have to store the password, the system key chain is the secure place for that. Look for  `SecKeychainAddGenericPassword` API function, it will lead you to [Keychain Services Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/conceptual/keychainServConcepts/03tasks/tasks.html) and examples.

Comment: Thanks. To be clear, I would never have stored a password as plain text. Like I say, this is an app which is a front to a web service (like a Twitter client or something) so I guess keychain would be best. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

create a nsobject Global class----

Global.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Global : NSObject 
extern NSString *gStrEmail;
extern NSString *gStrPassword;
```

@end

Global.m

```
#import "Global.h"

@implementation Global
NSString *gStrEmail=@"";
NSString *gStrPassword=@"";
@end
```

import this class in to 
   App_Prefix.pch

```
 #import "Global.h"
```

loginViewController.m

```
 gStrEmail=txtEmail.text;
 gStrPassword==txtEmail.text;
```

and use anywhere email and password  Strings